# .gitignore of the parent module affects add and commit of the child module

Tags: git

In my home directory, I have a git repository to track configuration files, such as .zshrc, .vimrc. The .gitignore file excludes all the files except these specified ones.

In my ~/Desktop/ directory, I have cloned one other project, and it has its own .gitignore. However, when I created new files in this child module and try to add and commit them. It always says "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

I try to delete the .gitignore of the parent module, and the child module can add and commit. This means "git add" of my child module is affected by the parent module's .gitignore. I also tried created dummy nested repositories, the .gitignore from parent did not affect its child repository. Now I am confused with this different behaviour.

This is parent's .gitignore

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files:
!.gitignore
!.zshrc
!.bash_profile
!.vimrc
```

Comment: When you say "submodule" do you mean a repository you cloned into a subdirectory of your home? Or do you mean you're using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: `git check-ignore -nv path/to/whatever` will tell you exactly where any rule matching that path came from.

Comment: try with add !*/ in parent's .gitignore file

Comment: @Schwen I mean a repository I cloned into a subdirectory. I did not use any `git submodule` explicitly. I thought that cloning a repository inside an existing repository, the cloned one is a submodule by default.

Comment: @jthill Thanks. The command is very helpful to know which .gitignore is actually applied. I checked that in the subdirectory the untracked files are affected by the parent's .gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Run

```
git config --global core.excludesFile <file name for global ignore patterns>
```

**Details**

In my experience, `.gitignore` in your home directory applies globally.

After some research, I found out that the setting `core.excludesFile` defines an ignores file that is to be read in every sandbox. On my Linux machine, that defaulted to `~/.gitignore`, while on my Windows machine it's somewhere else, I'm not sure where.

In your case, it's obviously in your home, so you need to change it so that you home Git repo's `.gitignore` is not also your global one:

```
git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore.global
```

Now, if there are things you want to ignore everywhere, you put them in that file, and your `~/.gitignore` will only apply to your home Git repo itself.

Comment: Thanks. I think the first line here is to ignore all the files in the current directory and not ignore anything in all sub directories. When we use `git add .` in parent directory, all the files in subdirectories will be added. i.e. all the files in ~/Desktop/, ~/Downloads/, etc will be added. This is not expected.

Comment: OK, agreed, that won't work then. I noticed something interesting: on my Windows machine, `~/.gitignore` was not read, but on my Linux machine it was, so I did some more research: the problem is actually with `core.excludefile` being set to read `~/.gitignore` globally. The solution is to change that setting. I'll rewrite my answer, now that I believe I have a real solution for you.

Comment: @Y.Zhou I just rewrote my answer completely with a correct solution, since my first solution was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

The problem occurred because the **~/.gitignore** file affects **globally** by default on Linux and MacOS (@joanis).

In this case, the global effect is not expected. I changed the path of the global gitignore file to `~/.gitignore_global` and created an empty `.gitignore_global` file at the path. The `~/.gitignore` remained the same. Thanks everyone helped~

### check the path of the global git ignore file

Use

`git config --get core.excludesfile`

the output shows the path of the global git ignore file, by default it is `~/.gitignore`.

### change the default global .gitignore

If we want to change the default global .gitignore, we can use

`git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'`

above changes the **path** of global default git ignore file to `~/.gitignore_global`.

If now look at `~/.gitconfig` file, we will find

```
[core]
  excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

### For Debug: check which .gitignore affects certain file

As @jthill mentioned,use

`git check-ignore -nv path/to/whatever`

The interpretation of the output from above command is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore#_output). If it shows `:: path/to/whatever` means the file or the directory is not affected by any git ignore pattern, and will be added when `git add theFile` is executed.